# jQuery .on() not working with mousenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events, jquery-on

I am trying to use `.on()`, since `.live()` is deprecated. Yet I can't get `.on()` to work.

I got this html part:

```
...
<div class="tile" data-position="0,0" style="top: 539.5px; left: 380px;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="image"><img src="bla.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="title">title1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile" data-position="0,1" style="top: 539.5px; left: 380px;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="image"><img src="bla.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="title">title2</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile" data-position="0,2" style="top: 539.5px; left: 380px;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="image"><img src="bla.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="title">title3</div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

and this jQuery:

```
$('.tile').on({
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        alert("enter");
        $(this).find('.content .image').animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 100);
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        alert("leave");
    }
});
```

No matter what syntax I use from the documentation from Jquery, it doesn't work.
Does any know what went wrong here? This syntax should work, it is pretty the same as in an example at jQuery.

Comment: Did you remember document.ready and to include jQuery first

Comment: Yes, I did include jQuery first. But you are saying I have to put this jQuery part in the document.ready()? seems kinda weird to me

Comment: And so it does seem to work now. Don't really understand why it has to in the document.ready() though.

Comment: It's in the documentation for jQuery. You either have to run your javascript inside a DOM ready handler, or after the elements are added to the DOM, otherwise there are no elements to work with.

Comment: Guess that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop those in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of `<body>`. This will ensure that the elements you're attaching these handlers do actually exist.

```
<script>
$('.tile').on({
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        alert("enter");
        $(this).find('.content .image').animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 100);
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        alert("leave");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

Or you could use DOM `ready` handler which will execute these events after DOM is loaded fully and all elements are available.

```
$(function() {
    $('.tile').on({
        mouseenter: function()
        {
            alert("enter");
            $(this).find('.content .image').animate({
                opacity: 0.5
            }, 100);
        },
        mouseleave: function()
        {
            alert("leave");
        }
    });
});
```

Or let the omnipresent `document` object delegate the event to `.tiles`:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        alert("enter");
        $(this).find('.content .image').animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 100);
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        alert("leave");
    }
},'.tile');
```